# Which Church is Ray a member of?

Tags: character, analysis, archer

In Archer S03E09, Ray's brother Randy says the following about Ray:

> Even though Ray used to be a preacher, he was never big on the Old
>   Testament.

Later in S05E11, Ray himself says the following:

> I actually don't know. My church didn't really do the New Testament.

I believe it was established, or implied, throughout the show, that Ray is a Christian although I don't have a specific reference. If that is the case, it seems like he has a relatively unique belief system as a Christian where neither the Old nor the New Testament have significance to him.

Is there any Christian sect or church that follows such model?

Comment: There are dozens of Christian groups that don't really follow the Bible as literal teaching. ELCA, some Anglicans and Roman Catholics, United Methodists, there are too many to distinguish here without more information.

Comment: I don't think this is ever brought again, so the simplest answer is "we don't know".

Comment: This is not a well formed question. It's not clear if you are trying to ask what sect Ray is from or if such a sect exists. If you want to ask if such a sect exists, then you can go over to the Christianity Stack Exchange